# Comparison in Where clause in MDX Queries

Tags: mdx, mondrian

In MDX Queries, How can i compare whether a level value is less than a certain value or not.
e.g.

```
SELECT NON EMPTY
    [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].Members ON 0,
    [Product].[Category].[Clothing] ON 1
FROM
    [Adventure Works]
WHERE
    ([Measures].[LowGPM] > 120)
```

This MDX query didn't work.

Also, i tried WITH Clause also.

```
WITH Member [Measures].[Calculated Measures] as
     IIF ([Measures].[LowGPM] < 120, [Measures].[LowGPM], null)

SELECT NON EMPTY
    [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].Members ON 0,
    [Product].[Category].[Clothing] ON 1
FROM
    [Adventure Works]
WHERE
    ([Measures].[LowGPM] > 120)
```

It shows Mondrian Error:`MDX object '[Measures].[Calculated Measures]' not found in cube`.

Comment: what would you like to filter, can you phrase this in English.. IMHO you're a bit mixed up

Answer (score 4):

You can filter the axis like this:

```
SELECT
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,
  Filter(
    [Customer].[Country].Members, 
    ([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] > 2000000) 
        AND ([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] < 5000000)
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: Yup, Filter() is what you need!